# FirebaseProvider not found even if firebase not added to the project

Tags: android, firebase

I have never added firebase in my project and eventhough I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wma.ozfoodhunter-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.wma.ozfoodhunter-1, /system/lib]]
                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4762)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4369) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4309) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this error occurs only when I run the app on KitKat.

When I tried to search whether I have used firebase in the project, I could find firebase only in the R files.

Could someone explain me why does the firebase got added in my R file, even if it is not used in the project.

My Gradle is

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.2.3'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.2.3'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.12.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.0.0'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:0.0.3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview:library:2.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: are using `instant run ` ? it can cause some error like this, and check you called multidex at your manifest file

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess. I would advise you to take a closer look at them

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with [version 9.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90), the Firebase APIs became bundled with the Google Play Services API.  When you have a dependency on:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

You get ALL of the Play Services APIs, including Firebase.  This makes your APK needlessly large, increases your build time, and often requires use of Multidex.

You should replace the dependency on `play-services` with the specific APIs you need.  They are listed in Table 1 of [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).